# Is Windows Store app PurchaseResults.TransactionId the same as receipt's ProductReceipt->Id?

Tags: windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, win-universal-app

Do somebody happen to know, when you do:

```
var purchase_result = await CurApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(product_id); 
string transaction_id= purchase_result.TransactionId.ToString();
```

is transaction_id the same as ProductReceipt->Id in purchase_result.ReceiptXml:

```
...
<ProductReceipt Id="c5318bba-4c8b-47f7-a6d5-f373f31c8b91" ProductId="mytestid1" PurchaseDate="2016-10-25T18:17:55Z" 
        ExpirationDate="9999-12-31T23:59:59Z" ProductType="Durable" AppId="myappid1"/>
...
```

(I can't check it currently in my environment, but I'd like to know it before all code will be written.)

Answer (score 1):

Tested on debug environment, looks like it's true.

Comment: You might check the your true Store receipt and compare it with the transaction id in the payout summary details in Dashboard. It's same.